# How to do Feature Extraction using Apache Spark

Tags: feature-selection, apache-spark, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, pyspark

I am a newbie to Machine Learning and I have to do feature extraction for a banking application to detect / predict fraudulent transactions.

I have come across few articles on Feature Extraction using Scipy / Sci-kit learn in Python but I want to know is there any way to do the same in Apache Spark using some packages or modules within Spark

Any ideas that enable me to use Pyspark is also welcomed here

Appreciating your thoughts on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! Learn to do it with pandas first; it uses the same paradigm.

Comment: Thanks @Emre but it would be good if you please elaborate your thoughts in detail on how to do Feature Extraction / Selection with Pandas

Comment: Do you know what feature extraction is?

Comment: Yes @CalZ theoretically

Comment: Say you have a data set with a date (MM/DD/YYYY) in it. Feature engineering would be adding a column to that for day of the week (Sunday to Saturday) so that you can detect activity on a weekend vs weekday. Google how to "add a column in pandas data frame" and then how to do it with a Spark data frame.

Comment: I got your point @CalZ but I have come across something called as "Automatic Selection of Features" in python that scans the input dataset and automatically selects the columns that give a near accurate prediction. But I do not understand how it is doing it. Is there any similar approach to identify important columns instead of adding new column for feature engineering ? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: That's a different question. http://alexperrier.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/08/27/feature-importance-random-forests-gini-accuracy.html

Comment: @CalZ Thank you for your pointers. Can you please let me know whether can we pass all the columns as features and determine the labels whether it is 0 or 1 like that

Comment: What do you mean by determine the labels? What you described sounds like regular machine learning - you pass in a bunch of inputs and it builds a model to predict the labels.

Comment: Yes @CalZ . For Example : Determining particular transaction as fraud or not based on few features(such as transactionCity, transactionCountry, etc...). Here the label 0 represents non-fraud transaction and label 1 represents fraud transaction.

Comment: OK, what you describe just sounds like regular supervised learning.

Comment: Yes @CalZ any inputs on how to achieve it ? There are so many useful articles out there but I do not see a good article exactly matching what is required to me

Comment: I recommend you start simple to understand what classification is, then try to reimplement in Spark: https://orange.biolab.si/docs/